# Rails: undefined method `users' with nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

Let's imagine that you have two specific kinds of users, the employeurs and prestataires. First you fill in the user form with general information (name, email, etc). Then, you choose between the prestataire or employeur form, which will save the user form and redirect you to the second part of the inscription. Both employeurs and prestataires models have a belong_to relation with users.

With the code below, I've been able to create and save the user form, be redirected to the employeur or prestataire form. Yet, when I create an employeur, I get an error: undefined method `users' for #, despite my nested routes:

```
resources :users do
    resources :employeurs
    resources :prestataires
  end
```

Here's my User Form and controller:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :civility, 'Titre de civilité: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :civility %>
  </div>
.
.
.
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Employeur" %>
    <%= f.submit "Prestataire" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
```

This part of the user controller creates an instance and redirects to employeur or prestataire form:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if params[:commit] == 'Prestataire'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The employeur controller:

```
class EmployeursController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @employeurs = Employeur.all
  end

  # GET /projets/1
  # GET /projets/1.json
  def show
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur
  end

  # GET /projets/1/edit
  def edit
  end


 def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @employeur = @user.create_employeur(employeur_params)
  end

  def create_employeur
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @employeur = Employeur.new(employeur_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.save
        format.html { redirect_to user_employeur_path(@user, @employeur), notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employeur }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private
  def employeur_params
    params.require(:employeur).permit(:siren, :societe, :code_postal)
  end


end
```

And and the employeur form:

```
<%= form_for [@user, @employeur] do |f| %>
  <% if @employeur.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@employeur.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employeur from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @employeur.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :siren, 'Siren: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :siren %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :societe, 'Société: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :societe %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code_postal, 'Code Postal: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :code_postal %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm pretty new to rails and therefore, I can't see any error... Thanks in advance for your help.

Due to the comments, I'm adding my models and the backtraces:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prestataire
  has_one :employeur

  has_secure_password
end

class Employeur < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projets, as: :projetable
  has_many :prestataires, through: :projets
  has_many :offres, through: :projets
  has_many :feedbacks, through: :projets
  validates :siren, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates_associated :users
end
```

Development log file:

```
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "offres" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "detail" text, "projet_id" integer, "prix" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (13.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "ouvriers" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "siret" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) 
  [1m[36m (17.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE INDEX "index_ouvriers_on_user_id" ON "ouvriers" ("user_id")[0m
  [1m[35m (20.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "patrons" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "societe" varchar(255), "siret" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) 
  [1m[36m (13.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE INDEX "index_patrons_on_user_id" ON "patrons" ("user_id")[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "projets" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "titre" varchar(255), "description" text, "prix_haut" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) 
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255), "password_digest" varchar(255), "nom" varchar(255), "prenom" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (18.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL) 
  [1m[36m (9.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT version FROM "schema_migrations"
  [1m[36m (9.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140427221811')[0m
  [1m[35m (8.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131101095837')
  [1m[36m (9.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131102103723')[0m
  [1m[35m (15.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103180052')
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103181116')[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103181222')
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (1.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (1.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (3.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (0.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (1.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (3.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (1.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (0.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:21', '2014-04-28 22:38:21', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (3.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (0.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:22', '2014-04-28 22:38:22', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:22', '2014-04-28 22:38:22', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mFixture Delete (0.0ms)[0m  DELETE FROM "offres"
  [1m[36mFixture Insert (1.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:22', '2014-04-28 22:38:22', 980190962)[0m
SQLite3::SQLException: table offres has no column named references: INSERT INTO "offres" ("detail", "references", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('MyText', NULL, '2014-04-28 22:38:22', '2014-04-28 22:38:22', 980190962)
  [1m[35m (2.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "employeurs" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "societe" varchar(255), "siren" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "code_postal" varchar(255)) [0m
  [1m[35m (5.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_employeurs_on_user_id" ON "employeurs" ("user_id")
  [1m[36m (5.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "feedbacks" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "score" integer, "commentaire" text, "projet_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (4.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_feedbacks_on_projet_id" ON "feedbacks" ("projet_id")
  [1m[36m (5.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "offres" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "projet_id" integer, "price" decimal(8,2), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (5.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_offres_on_projet_id" ON "offres" ("projet_id")
  [1m[36m (5.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "prestataires" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "siren" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (6.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_prestataires_on_user_id" ON "prestataires" ("user_id")
  [1m[36m (7.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "projets" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255), "description" text, "max_price" decimal(8,2), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "category" varchar(255), "delivery_date" time, "expiration_date" time, "projetable_id" integer, "projetable_type" varchar(255)) [0m
  [1m[35m (7.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_projets_on_projetable_id_and_projetable_type" ON "projets" ("projetable_id", "projetable_type")
  [1m[36m (7.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255), "password_digest" varchar(255), "surname" varchar(255), "forename" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "civility" varchar(255), "phone" varchar(255)) [0m
  [1m[35m (7.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL) 
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT version FROM "schema_migrations"
  [1m[36m (7.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140510205811')[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131101095837')
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131102103723')[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103180052')
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103181116')[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103181222')
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140427221811')[0m
  [1m[35m (15.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140428232839')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140428235011')[0m
  [1m[35m (34.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140428235712')
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140429001342')[0m
  [1m[35m (13.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504163617')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504165702')[0m
  [1m[35m (24.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504170115')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504170335')[0m
  [1m[35m (24.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504171748')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140507181545')[0m
  [1m[35m (15.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140510204225')
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  [1m[36m (6.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "employeurs" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "societe" varchar(255), "siren" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "code_postal" varchar(255)) [0m
  [1m[35m (5.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_employeurs_on_user_id" ON "employeurs" ("user_id")
  [1m[36m (6.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "feedbacks" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "score" integer, "commentaire" text, "projet_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (5.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_feedbacks_on_projet_id" ON "feedbacks" ("projet_id")
  [1m[36m (5.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "offres" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "projet_id" integer, "price" decimal(8,2), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (6.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_offres_on_projet_id" ON "offres" ("projet_id")
  [1m[36m (6.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "prestataires" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "siren" varchar(255), "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime) [0m
  [1m[35m (7.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_prestataires_on_user_id" ON "prestataires" ("user_id")
  [1m[36m (7.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "projets" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255), "description" text, "max_price" decimal(8,2), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "category" varchar(255), "delivery_date" time, "expiration_date" time, "projetable_id" integer, "projetable_type" varchar(255)) [0m
  [1m[35m (9.0ms)[0m  CREATE INDEX "index_projets_on_projetable_id_and_projetable_type" ON "projets" ("projetable_id", "projetable_type")
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "users" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "email" varchar(255), "password_digest" varchar(255), "surname" varchar(255), "forename" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "civility" varchar(255), "phone" varchar(255)) [0m
  [1m[35m (9.0ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar(255) NOT NULL) 
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT version FROM "schema_migrations"
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140510205811')[0m
  [1m[35m (8.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131101095837')
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131102103723')[0m
  [1m[35m (8.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103180052')
  [1m[36m (8.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103181116')[0m
  [1m[35m (8.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20131103181222')
  [1m[36m (13.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140427221811')[0m
  [1m[35m (15.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140428232839')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140428235011')[0m
  [1m[35m (15.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140428235712')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140429001342')[0m
  [1m[35m (15.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504163617')
  [1m[36m (27.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504165702')[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504170115')
  [1m[36m (15.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504170335')[0m
  [1m[35m (27.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140504171748')
  [1m[36m (14.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140507181545')[0m
  [1m[35m (14.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES ('20140510204225')
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

Comment: Can you post the backtrace?

Comment: Let's see your models.

Comment: Cant see any error either - can you post your models & backtrace? The error you presented is *very* ambiguous

Comment: I think I've done it. I just hope that the bakctrace you're asking are equivalent to the log file.